# ajax field validation in struts2 not reloading the same form

Tags: validation, jquery, struts2

I've been trying to use the field-validation framework in Struts2 and have it implemented.  The problem is when doing an AJAX call with jquery tags, it targets a resulting div when I want to reload the same page with the fielderror.

```
<div class="myform">
    <s:form id="userForm" action="users" theme="simple">
        <h1>Search for Users</h1>
        <p><s:fielderror /></p>
        <label>Username
            <span class="small">Add your name</span>
        </label>
        <s:textfield id="username" name="username"/>
        <label>Point Minimum
            <span class="small">Min. 0 points</span>
        </label>
        <s:textfield name="pointMin"/>

        <label>Point Maximum
            <span class="small">Max. 5000 points</span>
        </label>
        <s:textfield name="pointMax"/>

        <label>Rate Minimum
            <span class="small">Percentage</span>
        </label>
        <s:textfield id="rateMin" name="rateMin"/>

        <label>Rate Maximum
            <span class="small">Percentage</span>
        </label>
        <s:textfield id="rateMax" name="rateMax"/>

        <s:hidden name="searchButtonHit" value="%{true}"/>
        <sj:a formIds="userForm" 
              targets="listingDisplay" 
              button="true"
              validate="only"
              type="submit"> Search
        </sj:a>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
    </s:form>
</div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div id="listingDisplay"></div>
```

The `<sj:a>` tag targets the `listingDisplay` div so the `fielderror` as well as the same form is loaded underneath which looks very strange.  Is there a better way of doing this? Thanks!

Comment: yes there is, better use simple jquery in-place of using jquery plugin i have faced same behaviors while using the plugin and ended up using jquery which is more clean and why wrap jquery inside some tags?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the below validation link. It adds a string errorhere to the error message and checks for it after response. You can also do this to reload the page and the reload code can be written in 's onSuccessTopics.

[Ajax Validation](http://www.onlinexamples.com/showfullexample.action?idexamples=67&title=Jquery%20Grid%20Server%20Side%20Validation,%20Error%20Shown%20On%20The%20Grid%20Form%20Itself)

Method 2

Very simple but may not work on all browsers.
Set the targets attribute of

```
 <sj:a targets="myform">
```

to the same div, within which the form exists.